# Feasibility of cold-blooded Livestock

Tags: biology, fauna, food, agriculture

The research I have done recently (searching through Wikipedia) has yielded that generally cold-blooded animals (Ectotherms) are able to survive on less food that their warm-blooded counterparts, and their low resting metabolic rate allowed them to grow faster.

Thus, would an ectotherm animal be better suited for livestock than an endotherm? Or are there big disadvantages that make Ectotherms less suitable to be used in that role?

Comment: You mean like fish? Farmed salmon etc.?

Comment: *"The reported output from global aquaculture operations in 2019 was over 120 million tonnes valued at US$274 billion"* says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Aquaculture&oldid=1214317831). (For comparison, total worldwide beef production is some 340 million tonnes, and poultry meat production is about 100 million tonnes.)

Comment: You also have farmed crocodiles and alligators.

Comment: A large part of why they can survive on less is because they grow less, it's entirely possible to farm any number of large reptiles (I can imagine marine Iguanas farmed for meat as a cool idea for world building) but it's better economically and more efficient (or at least faster) to use warm bloods, so in the real world their meat will probably always be a novelty niche product like farmed alligator rather than a staple .. but don't let that stop you if you really want it.

Comment: Also snails, frogs, worms and insects! All of which are already farmed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest shortcoming would be the growth rate: as in any business, your goal of growing livestock is maximizing profit. If your livestock takes 6 years to reach commercial size, and your competitors grow a different species that takes only 2 years, you will have 1/3 of their revenue, all the rest being the same.

This is why chicken, cows and company get pumped with hormones, plants with fertilizers and so on: to shorten the time it takes to reach commercial size.

Cold blooded animals have generally a slower growth rate, thus it could be more challenging to grow them commercially, especially if there are warm blooded competing species.